# what are the options to implement distributed persisted atomic counters? is redis the best option or is there any other technology that can utilized?

Tags: redis, persistence, counter, atomic, distributed

I wanted to implement a global distributed persisted atomic counter. The only option that came to my mind is to use Redis incr() but since redis doesn't provide persistence and when the redis cluster goes down, the counters are out of sync.

Is there any other technology that provides the option of persistence along with distributed atomic counters?

Answer (score 0):

Redis does provide persistence [enter link description here](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)

There are two options

RDB = snapshot
AOF = write log

The article describes the use cases and pros/cons